# How to create a Hibernate mapping in IntelliJ and H2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, h2

I connect h2 database and Hibernate in IntelliJ, but when I run the JPA Console I receive this:

> StudentBean is not mapped [from StudentBean]

[image]

I am new in Hibernate and I will be crateful if someone shom me step by step how to mapping classes in JPA Hibernate

P.S. I awready import all necessary libraries

Comment: Please can you show us your StudentBean class?

Comment: Post all the relevant code and configuration, as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with maping is resolved for me:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCSkF.png)

On the image you can see the correct path tree and my jar libraries.
But this path working for desctop app not for web.